# How do we use minus numbers for step in range

Tags: python

I tried to use -1 for the step in range to reverse the list, in the first code it gave an empty list and in the second, I got what I wanted.

```py
print(list(range(0, 5, -1)))
# Output: []

print(list(range(5, -1, -1)))
# Output: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

How do we understand this?

Comment: OK, thanks, I got the first part. But how do we understand the second?

Answer (score 1):

The range generator does a sanity check. If *start* is lower than *end* and *step* is negative then that's impossible - hence the empty list. In your case, you can never get to 5 by decrementing from zero.

In the second case, the range generator will stop generating when *end* has been reached - i.e. it does not generate the value of *end*

Comment: Aha, got it, so it goes till -1 excluding -1, which is 0. I was stuck in using -1. The concept is the number before -1 is 0. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`range(0, 5, -1)` -> starting at `0`, you cannot reach `5` by successively adding `-1`. No numbers are encountered along the way.

`range(5, -1, -1)` -> starting at `5`, you can reach `-1` by successively adding `-1`, and it yields the numbers that it'll encounter along the way.

Answer (score 0):

`range` function is working like this if you add 3 arguments :

```
range(begin, end, step)
```

In this case you will begin from `begin` value, and by implementing the `step`, reach the `(end - abs(step))` value at the end. Remember in python as the end is not reached (which differs from other languages such as **Matlab** for example).

You must take care of your implementation step according to the value you add as begin and end. It must be consistent, as [@Kache](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234593/kache) was saying.